# fread() reading from a descriptor based on a pipe sets error, not EOF where there is no data

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fread

I need to read with fread() the stuff from the read end of the pipe.

But while i expect the fread() to set EOF when there is nothing in the pipe, it instead sets the error indicator. I have checked the posix and C standards and found no clue there. Probably i'm doing something unintended (read, silly), right:)

Here's the excerpt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
   char buf[128];
   FILE *f;
   int pipe_fd[2], n;

   pipe(pipe_fd);
   fcntl(pipe_fd[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

   f=fdopen(pipe_fd[0], "r");
   n=fread(buf, 1, 1, f);
   printf("read: %d, Error: %d, EOF: %d\n", n, ferror(f), feof(f));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using a non-blocking pipe, I believe you would get:

- `errno==EAGAIN` when there simply isn't anything there to read (meaning nothing now but maybe something later - try (e)again later).
- `EOF` when the writing side of the pipe is closed (meaning no more data is coming).

See the manpage for `read()` about how read() behaves when O_NONBLOCK mode is set.  `fread()` behavior should be consistent with read().

Comment: Thank You, Bert! Looks like it. So the EAGAIN is just propagated up to the streams level and results in error set. So my approach won't work.  Just trying to cope with lex in a standard way:) Shall look further...

Comment: Yeah, think about it, if it returned EOF when the pipe is temporarily blocked, then the receiver wouldn't be able to tell if all the data has come in yet. You couldn't write any programs that do any real work (with pipes) if it worked like that, unless you had some protocols to re-connect to get the rest of the data.