# Can you transmit whole int and char for the same pipe in c?

Tags: c, pipe

Is it possible to transmit whole numbers (int) and characters (char) for the same pipe or do I need to create two different pipes? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pipes are handled like *files* and so you can use the standard file i/o commands to write any format you want, i.e. `write`, `read`, `fwrite`, `fread`, `fprintf`, `fscanf` , ...

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

( [Why fprintf and fscanf does not work with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349397/why-fprintf-and-fscanf-does-not-work-with-pipe), [fread() reading from a descriptor based on a pipe sets error, not EOF where there is no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377210/fread-reading-from-a-descriptor-based-on-a-pipe-sets-error-not-eof-where-ther) )